# What did Steve Trevor mean by him being above average?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

In *Wonder Woman* (2017) movie, there was [this conversation](https://youtu.be/UYE8E9UiYTM?t=1m31s) between Steve Trevor and Diana:

> Steve Trevor: Ah.. I didn't see you come in.
>   Wonder Woman: Would you say you are a... a typical example of your sex?
>   Steve Trevor: **I am... above average.**
>   Wonder Woman: What's that?

Having seen a human male for the first time in her life, Diana was obviously curious. But, what did Steve Trevor mean when he said he was above average? In what respect he considered himself above average? IQ? Strength? Physique?

Comment: The gag is that he's talking about his penis.

Comment: I didn't realize the joke was that subtle...

Comment: @Vanguard3000 I am a kid without dirty mind unless you tease me. Okay?

Comment: @Vanguard3000 - It's not. It's really not

Comment: I just cross-checked with my wife. She kinda thought it could be about that, but anecdotally it may be that the joke really isn’t as obvious to women than men? Just speculating here...

Comment: @flq user Christie Romanowski is, in fact, a male human being, so that doesn't really help.

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious. He's standing there, buck naked, and she asks him that while peeking at his dangly bits.

Comment: @Devar-TTY No, she wasn't peeking at his dangly bits. When she asked "What's that?", then Steve Trevor thought about her getting peek at it, but then he followed her eyes to the watch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He's talking about the size of his penis.

In multiple interviews Pine stressed that "every man knows what he's talking about" and that it was a "dumb man thing"

Comment: How does "every man knows about it" imply penis size?

Comment: @ChristieRomanowski - The interviewer is **staring right at his junk** when he asks the question.

Comment: Today I learned that I'm not a man. ;)

Comment: There's a lot of winking and looking very happy at the sauciness of the joke.

Comment: Pine and Gadot discuss his penis here;; https://web.archive.org/web/20170601012709/http://moviehole.net/2017117211gal-gadot-chris-pine-wonder-woman

Answer (score 6):

He considers himself above average *as an example of his sex*, i.e. in "manly" qualities: strength, masculine physique, courage, etc. But he's mostly talking about attractiveness (which is a composite of these and other factors). He probably also thinks that Diana is just asking about his penis, but she's asking about him in general. (If you watch her eyes, it's clear that she's only looking at his face, and then at his watch, which is much more interesting.)

Think about the subtext of this conversation: It's obvious (here and in earlier scenes) that Diana finds Steve attractive. But he's the first and so far only man she's ever seen, so she wants to know whether all men are like this, or if he's special. She knows that the chances that the one man who crashed near her secret island *just happens* to be exceptionally good-looking are slim--that's what "exceptional" means. (*We* know that the chances are 100%, because that's how casting works.) Steve wants her to know that he's definitely special.

[image: Steve Trevor making a totally obvious bid for Diana's attention]

At least, *he* thinks he's special, but given that he's an Air Force Officer, he's probably right that he's stronger and has a "better" physique than the average man. He also proves himself, over the rest of the movie, to be courageous, intelligent, and savvy.

Comment: Uh... Noooo. And please don't add reference pictures.

Comment: @amflare OF HIS FACE JEEZ

Comment: Honestly I always thought that was all they were talking about. I thought the joke was that the first man she met happened to be an extremely good-looking international secret agent, and that "above average" was an understatement.

Comment: This answer does a very good job showing how a joke about his penis is clean enough to stay in a Disney movie.